# Is it possible to sort by the sequence of input IDs?

Tags: postgresql, order-by, sorting

I want to find a user's favorite music list. First step, I query all `id` from user's `favorite` table. In the next step I query the music list by `id` from `songs` table. But now I want to sort rows by the timestamp column `favorite.added_at` desc.

I do not want to join table, so I want to figure out if it's possible to sort by the input id in the in query.
For example:

```
-- the 3087 is first record
select *
from songs s 
where id in (3087,5122)

-- the 5122 is first record
select *
from songs s 
where id in (5122,3087)
```

I have tried in PostgreSQL 13, and the row with `id = 3087` was always first. Seems like PostgreSQL does not fetch rows by the sequence of values in the `IN` list?

Comment: Is the query being passed to PostgreSQL as a complete string, or are you using prepared statements when querying?

Comment: I execute this in DBeaver, the orm framework when running app is rust diesel. Is this effect the query result @matigo

Answer (score 2):

There is a fundamental flaw with your approach, in that you first select the favorites and then fetch the song details in a second query. Not only are you lacking a good `ORDER BY` clause for the second query, but splitting a task like that in two queries causes unnecessary work.

You can improve performance and solve your problem in one step by solving the complete problem in a single query that joins both tables. Then the `ORDER BY` clause would come natural.

Answer (score 2):

#### Sort order

> Seems like PostgreSQL does not fetch rows by the sequence of values in the `IN` list?

The order of values passed to `IN` is **insignificant**. Postgres is a liberty to return rows in arbitrary order unless determined with `ORDER BY`.

You could pass a **set** and add an "ordering" column.
But it's much simpler to pass an **array** and work with the given order of elements. Use `unnest()` and append [**`WITH ORDINALITY`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

```
-- 3087 first
SELECT s.*
FROM   unnest('{3087,5122}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS i(id, ord)
JOIN   song s USING (id)
ORDER  BY ord;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=be3af7f4de4f72a2382a52016f71edab)*

See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/939860)

Another important difference: while duplicates in an `IN` list (or set) are removed, they are kept as given when joining to an unnested array.

#### Proper solution

Assuming both tables (`favorite` and `songs`) reside in the same DB, it would be **much better** to run a single query:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM   favorite f
JOIN   song s ON s.id = f.song_id
WHERE  f.user_id = 123
ORDER  BY f.added_at DESC;
```

Then you can order by `favorite.added_at` directly. And it's a single round-trip to the DB server.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to do something like this (a fiddle with all of the code below is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=03644952034e65fb6dae264837c3a95c)):

```
CREATE TABLE song
(
  song_id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  song_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  song_artist TEXT NOT NULL
  --
  -- more fields
  --
);
```

populate it:

```
INSERT INTO song (song_name, song_artist) VALUES 
('x song  1', 'artist  1'),
('y song  2', 'artist  2'),  -- the reason for the letters is that songs 
('k song  3', 'artist  3'),  -- in a collection are unlikely to be in 
('c song  4', 'artist  4'),  -- alphabetical order
('b song  5', 'artist  5'),
('l song  6', 'artist  6'),
('m song  7', 'artist  7'),
('a song  8', 'artist  8'),
('a song  9', 'artist  9'),
('b song 10', 'artist 10');
```

So now, if you run a query like this:

```
SELECT
  s.song_name, s.song_artist
FROM 
  song s
WHERE s.song_id IN (3, 5)
UNION
SELECT
  s.song_name, s.song_artist
FROM 
  song s
WHERE s.song_id IN (2, 8);
```

You will obtain a result like this<sup>**(1)**</sup>:

```
song_name   song_artist
y song  2   artist  2
b song  5   artist  5
a song  8   artist  8
k song  3   artist  3
```

where `(3, 5)` and `(2, 8)` are "mixed up". **NOTE:** you are not guaranteed to obtain this **exact** result on any run of the fiddle or on your own system - the SQL Standard says that without an `ORDER BY` clause in a query, the results can be returned in any order!

On a table with thousands of records (with `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s thrown into the mix), predicting the sort order of any resultset (without an `ORDER BY`) is going to be impossible.

<sup>**(1)**</sup> I was surprised by this result - I expected the query to return results in `PRIMARY KEY` order, but it doesn't - at least not today on this particular fiddle - proving that `ORDER BY` **always** needs to be specified. Just because a non-specified order is returned today (just good luck? whatever?), doesn't mean that your results will be returned in that order tomorrow!

So, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  'query 1' AS the_query, s.song_name, s.song_artist
FROM 
  song s
WHERE s.song_id IN (3, 1, 5)
UNION
SELECT
  'query 2', s.song_name, s.song_artist
FROM 
  song s
WHERE s.song_id IN (2, 8)
ORDER BY the_query, song_name;
```

Result:

```
the_query   song_name   song_artist
query 1     b song  5   artist  5
query 1     k song  3   artist  3
query 1     x song  1   artist  1
query 2     a song  8   artist  8
query 2     y song  2   artist  2
```

Which is correct (note the sequences `(b, k, x)` and `(a, y)`.

I introduced an `"artificial"` sorting key into this query - the `the_query` string which can be used to separate the results of the different queries in the `ORDER BY`. This can be useful in cases such as this!

Or, if you simply want to sort by `song_id` within the different queries:

```
SELECT
  'query 1' AS the_query, s.song_id, s.song_name, s.song_artist
FROM 
  song s
WHERE s.song_id IN (3, 1, 5)
UNION
SELECT
  'query 2', s.song_id, s.song_name, s.song_artist
FROM 
  song s
WHERE s.song_id IN (2, 8)
ORDER BY the_query, song_id;
```

Result:

```
the_query   song_id     song_name   song_artist
query 1           1     x song  1   artist  1
query 1           3     k song  3   artist  3
query 1           5     b song  5   artist  5
query 2           2     y song  2   artist  2
query 2           8     a song  8   artist  8
```

Again, because we've specified the `ORDER BY`, we get what we asked for (it does what it says on the tin!).

### EDIT:

On rereading the question, it appears that the OP wants the order of records to reflect the order of the `song_id`s in the `IN(...)` clause (fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=03644952034e65fb6dae264837c3a95c)).

This can be done as follows:

Imagine we want the songs with ids `5`, `8` and `2` to be presented in that order in the resultset.

So, we might try:

```
SELECT
  s.song_name, s.song_artist
FROM 
  song s
WHERE s.song_id IN (5, 8, 3);
-- ORDER BY s.song_id DESC;
```

**But**, the result (on my fiddle today) is:

```
song_name   song_artist
k song  3   artist  3
b song  5   artist  5
a song  8   artist  8
```

So, it's in order of song_id - but there is **no guarantee** that this will happen next week, tomorrow or even in the next second. I can guarantee or reverse this adding the `ORDER BY s.song_id ASC/DESC`.

PostgreSQL will resuse space in pages when records are deleted so records **may well not be** in `PRIMARY KEY` order on disk. Unlike some other systems, PostgreSQL does not have [clustered indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251652/470530).

If you want a cast-iron guarantee that the records will appear as you put them into the list in the `IN (...)` clause, then you have to do the following:

```
SELECT 
  s.song_id, 
  s.song_name, 
  s.song_artist, 
  t.id, 
  t.id_sort_order
FROM
  song s
JOIN
(
  VALUES(1, 5), (2, 8), (3, 2)
) AS t (id_sort_order, id) 
ON s.song_id = t.id
ORDER BY t.id_sort_order;
```

You use the `VALUES` clause to construct an `"artificial"`  table with two fields - one is your `id_sort_order` (1,2,3) and the other is your `id` which is your desired sort order (5,8,3) and then `JOIN` on the desired sort order to retrieve the details you want about songs (5,8,3), but you sort by (1,2,3), thereby obtaining your desired order in your final result set.

Result:

```
song_id     song_name   song_artist     id  id_sort_order
      5     b song  5   artist  5        5              1
      8     a song  8   artist  8        8              2
      2     y song  2   artist  2        2              3
```

The methods outlined above are the only ones which will guarantee your sort order.

Comment: The "surprise" in your `UNION` query goes away when you use `UNION ALL` (as appropriate). But that's a tangent to the actual question, as you clarified yourself.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - why is `UNION ALL` appropriate? I would think that the context of this query implies that any duplicate would be an error - therefore `UNION` is appropriate in this case? Is there any way of making `VALUES` into a set-returning function? See the last snippet [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4b798c67e4d52525da7bc4c0354f380b) - the query **always** returns in the order given in the VALUEs clause. I know that a few tests on a fiddle do not a summer make, but just wondering? Or is that a new question?

Comment: Multiple unioned `SELECT` would only make sense to keep multiple lists apart (I interpreted), hence `UNION ALL`, but that's all moot now. You can't attach `WITH ORDINALITY` to a `VALUES` expression directly - if that's what you are after. Else, yes, new question! ;)